# Планирует с 2015 года или С 2015 года планирует?

Tags: грамотная-речь, смысл, порядок-слов

Начиная с 2015 года компания планирует ежемесячно производить выплаты. Или правильнее: Компания планирует начиная с 2015 года ежемесячно производить выплаты.

Answer (score 2):

**Второй** вариант, несомненно, лучше. ***Компания планирует начиная с 2015 года ежемесячно производить выплаты.***

В первом предложении возникает двусмысленность.

Answer (score 1):

Тут разный смысл. Планирует с 2015-го или же производить с 2015?

Двусмысленности в первом варианте не вижу, тут однозначно получается: именно что планирует - уже второй год, - но не производит. Как-то так. И я не уверен, что это не тот смысл, который вкладывается.

Answer (score 0):

А вот не было бы этого "начиная" – и не было бы вообще никаких вопросов.